# Mismatch on checking memory usage in Linux

Tags: linux, memory, performance

I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10-24) where there is 64MB RAM in system.

Now I am checking the memory usage in the system, and I found the *mismatch* of the data.

First, the memory usage from kernel code and data,

```
Memory: 53424K/65536K available (7878K kernel code, 690K rwdata, 1744K rodata, 364K init, 337K bss, 12112K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
```

The size of memory available to the system is `53424KB`.

The output of `free -k` is as follows,

```
/ # free -k
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          53788       39148       13704           0         936       12960
Swap:             0           0           0
```

The output of `cat /proc/meminfo` is as follows,

```
/ # cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:          53788 kB
MemFree:           13692 kB
MemAvailable:      12948 kB
Buffers:               0 kB
Cached:              900 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:              832 kB
Inactive:            240 kB
Active(anon):          4 kB
Inactive(anon):      172 kB
Active(file):        828 kB
Inactive(file):       68 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                 4 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:           192 kB
Mapped:              848 kB
Shmem:                 0 kB
KReclaimable:        372 kB
Slab:               6320 kB
SReclaimable:        372 kB
SUnreclaim:         5948 kB
KernelStack:         360 kB
PageTables:           40 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:       26892 kB
Committed_AS:        532 kB
VmallocTotal:    1048372 kB
VmallocUsed:        2240 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:              200 kB
```

The kernel memory usage is the sum of "Buffers+Slab+KernelStack+PageTables" = `7620K`.

Running `$(ps -o pid,comm,rss,vsz | awk '{print $3}' | grep -v RSS)`, and the sum of the RSS of each process is about `4120K`.

So after system boots up, the sum of memory usage of kernel and user space is `7620 + 4120 = 11740K`.

But `free -k` shows the `used` memory is about `39148K`, which is a big mismatch.

Why there is the big mismatch, and how to precisely calculate memory usage in kernel and user space in Linux ?